# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.javaflow.core.StackRecorder

Tags: java, jasper-reports, apache-commons

When filling my Jasper Report I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.javaflow.core.StackRecorder
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:162)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:145)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:689)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:670)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:992)
```

I've already added `commons-javaflow` (https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22commons-javaflow%22) - but this does not help. Where to find this class?

EDIT: one comment to the duplicate question tag: this is not a general question about ClassNotFoundException - this is a special question concerning Jasper-Reports / Apache Commons JavaFlow. So please take away this tag.

Comment: Do you actually need javaflow?  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40545982/983559

If you do need it, what JasperReports version are you using?

Comment: @dada67 yes, very good hint - I've removed javaflow from my classpath, and now it works! Thank you! Only one remark concerning your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40545982/983559: the Commons Javaflow jar does not contain `org.apache.commons.javaflow.core.StackRecorder`- I therefore searched and found https://github.com/vsilaev/tascalate-javaflow - this contains it. Adding it to the classpath also fixes this exception! But the solution, not adding javaflow at all, for sure is much more better!

Comment: You're right, I updated the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40545982/983559 to talk about the switch to tascalate-javaflow.  I'll post an answer to this question as well for better visibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with JasperReports 6.6.0, [tascalate-javaflow](https://github.com/vsilaev/tascalate-javaflow) is used instead of Apache Commons Javaflow, so you'll need a net.tascalate.javaflow.api jar on the classpath (at the current moment, JasperReports lists [net.tascalate.javaflow.api-2.2.1.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=net/tascalate/javaflow/net.tascalate.javaflow.api/2.2.1/net.tascalate.javaflow.api-2.2.1.jar) as a dependency).

But the first thing that you need to do is to decide whether you actually need the Javaflow JasperReports variant.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40545982/983559) for a description on when the Javaflow variant is meant to be used.